# When I modify a nested dictionary, the other dictionaries nested with it are modified

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to extract RGB, HSV, and LAB values from every pixel in a list of images and sum the results for each image. Right now, I am focusing on summing the R,G, and B values. I am using a nested dictionary to store the data by image name, and colorspace.

```
from skimage import io, color

# Define images to analyze
images = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg']

# Create a dictionary of RGB image
read_images = {img:{} for img in images}
for i in images:
    read_images[i]['rgb'] = io.imread('./{}'.format(i))

# Define color spaces and create a dictionary to store data
color_spaces = ['rgb']
colors = {cs:{cs[0]:0, cs[1]:0, cs[2]:0} for cs in color_spaces}
img_data = {img:colors for img in images}

for img in images: # Select image
    for cs in color_spaces: # Select colorspce
        # Start Reading Image
        for line in read_images[img][cs]:
            for pixel in line:
                # Store pixel values
                val0, val1, val2 = pixel
                img_data[img][cs][cs[0]] += val0
                img_data[img][cs][cs[1]] += val1
                img_data[img][cs][cs[2]] += val2
```

I want the output of this to be:

```
img_data = {
            'pic1':{
                    'rgb':{
                          r: sum of r-values for pic1
                          g: sum of g-values for pic1
                          b: sum of b-valuse for pic1}}
            'pic2':{
                    'rgb':{
                          r: sum of r-values for pic2
                          g: sum of g-values for pic2
                          b: sum of b-valuse for pic2
                         }
                     }}
```

The issue is that each time it loops through the images list, it is adding that image's RGB values to the rgb dicts for both pictures, so that the sum of the R,G, and B values are of pic1+pic2 for both images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your images are sharing a single copy of the `colors` (`{"rgb": {"r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0}}`) dictionary, you need to make a copy for each image using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). We use `deepcopy` here since you need to make a copy of a nested dictionary.

Specifically, the line

```
img_data = {img:colors for img in images}
```

should be changed to:

```
import copy

img_data = {img: copy.deepcopy(colors) for img in images}
```

Without doing this, when you later come to modify the `colors` dictionaries inside `img_data`, you will be modifying a single copy of the dictionary in memory, regardless of which image you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You are lost in your own dict comprehensions... and merely reassigning different names to the same object as pointed by @dspencer

```
# Define color spaces and create a dictionary to store data
color_spaces = ['rgb']
img_data = {}
for img in images:
    for cs in color_spaces:
        for element in cs:
            if img not in img_data:
                img_data[img] = {}
            if cs not in img_data[img]:
                img_data[img][cs] = {}
            img_data[img][cs][element] = 0

for img in images:  # Select image
    for cs in color_spaces:  # Select colorspce
        # Start Reading Image
        for line in read_images[img][cs]:
            for pixel in line:
                # Store pixel values
                val0, val1, val2 = pixel
                img_data[img][cs][cs[0]] += val0
                img_data[img][cs][cs[1]] += val1
                img_data[img][cs][cs[2]] += val2
print(img_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr = np.transpose(np.array(Image.open(images[0], 'hsv')), (2,0,1))
np.sum(arr[0]), np.sum(arr[1]), np.sum(arr[2])
```

Easy way to generate the sum of r, g and b values.

Also you convert your rgb image to hsv as follows :

```py
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
rgb_img = Image.open(images[0])
hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img)
```